# UIView animation in iphone retina display is not smooth

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, retina-display

I want a roll-up animation for the uiview. So i am animating a mainscrollview and a rollupboard. So in the viewDidLoad i set the frame of these two views as:

```
    dashRollUpStand=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,346,320,0)];
    mainScrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,346,300,0)];
```

And i also have many subviews for this mainScrollView.

Now i am loading this view with a roll-up animation using the following code:

```
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
 [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIAnimationCurveLinear];

 [dashRollUpStand setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,346)];
 [mainScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(10,9,300,337)];
 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

This rollup animation is working fine in iphone. But on iphone retina display this animation is not at all smooth. So how can i make it smooth in iphone retina display.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are adding your views in viewDidLoad and having them offscreen?

<s>It seems to me that you should do it like this. In the code below `containerView` is the view that *contains your views*, `toView` is the view you are flipping *to* and `fromView` is the view you are flipping *from*.</s>

```
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
                  duration:1.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                animations:^{ 
                    [fromView removeFromSuperview]; 
                    [containerView addSubview:toView]; 
                }
                completion:NULL];
```

I also chose to use the block-based animation/transition API which is [the recommended way](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1) since iOS 4.

#### EDIT:

Since you are not actually transitioning the view, even though your original code did. You could just use a normal animation block instead

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                     [dashRollUpStand setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,346)];
                     [mainScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(10,9,300,337)];
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
```

Comment: i cant use this because i want a roll-up animation. My view has to move up from a roll-up stand. so the view height should increase gradually from the roll-up stand to get that effect.

Comment: But you are flipping the views?

Comment: Sorry actually i'm not flipping the views. First i will add the view with its height as 0. After this i will call for animation to change the frame of the subviews. I tried setting uianimationcurve - UIAnimationCurveLinear , but it too is not giving a smooth effect

Comment: Why were you using `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight` in the first place?

Comment: I used this accedently. but this option is also giving almost the same effect.

Comment: Isn't this almost like presenting a modal view?

Comment: i tried your code. The Same effect. Animation is not smooth. Is it because i have many subviews for my mainscrollview.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12292/discussion-between-david-ronnqvist-and-priyanka-v)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the kind of animations you are using, but more probably what you have iside your views. First of all try to make sure that subviews inside your animated view are opaque, opaque is a property of UIView, but it is overridden if the alpha of the view is less that 1. The rendering system requires more clicles to blend clear views, if you can go for opaque.

Comment: None of the subviews has alpha < 1.

Comment: what about opaque property? are they set to yes?

Comment: yes. i tried it after your suggestion. its not making any difference.

Comment: The only way to understand is try using instruments, with time profiler or core animation (the last one to check FPS). Without any code is difficult to understand, but if do not find any solution one could be get an image of the current screen and animate this, removing all the subviews...